# Webview is not detected by appium webdriver on real IOS device

Tags: java, ios, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am running the tests on a hybrid app. My configuration is: Xcode version set to '9.2' (tools v9.3.0.0.1.1521514116), Appium 1.7.2, and the capabilities are:

```html
capabilities.setCapability("xcodeConfigFile", "/path/to/xcodeConfigFile.xcconfig");
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 600);
capabilities.setCapability("nativeWebTap", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", chromeDriver);
capabilities.setCapability("bootstrapPath", "/Upath/to/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
capabilities.setCapability("udid", UDID);
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2.6");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platform);
capabilities.setCapability("app", iOSAppPath);
capabilities.setCapability("automationName" ,  "XCUITest");
```

If I use capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", "true") the tests is stuck at driver initialization, as it does not find any webview.

webDriver.getContextHandles() returns only NATIVE_APP on a real device, but also returns WEBVIEW_2908.1 on the simulator.

The external libraries used are:

```html
SaxonLiaison.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
guice-3.0.jar
java-client-4.1.2.jar
jcommander.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar
reportng-1.1.4.jar
saxon-8.7.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
smslib-3.5.4.jar
testng-6.8.21.jar
velocity-dep-1.4.jar
xslt.jar
```

I am unable to update to newer version because I get errors for some functionalities implemented in java-client-4.1.2.jar (for example webDriver.tap() )

As found on appium.io and other questions, I installed everything I could, like: ios-webkit-debug-proxy, libimobiledevice and ios-deploy

Edit: before I did not know that I had to manually run ios_webkit_debug_proxy, so I ran it three times with three different ports: 9221, 9222 and 9223, I received the same result and this is the only thing that was logged in the terminal:

```html
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c <udid>:9222
Connected :9222 to iPhone X (<udid>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my issue here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7676

I just had to start ios_webkit_debug_proxy and start appium server with a parameter that points to the ios_webkit_debug_proxy port

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c UDID:27753 -d

appium --no-reset --webkit-debug-proxy-port 27753
```